# Why do all my procedures run when I import mysqldump file?

Tags: mysql, routines

I execute the following statement from the cmd terminal to import my MySQL Database:

```
mysql u- root p- database < "C:\Users\Tom\data.sql"
```

When I open my MySQL Database from the MySQL Workbench I've realised that more tables have been created that I don't recognise. Basically, what is happening is the stored procedures/routines I have created seem to be automatically running and thus creating many more tables? I don't want this, I'd rather execute routines as I wish using the "Call" statements in MySQL, is there a way stop this happening?

Comment: Sorry, just don't believe that. Do you have events in place which may call the SPs? Perhaps disabling the event scheduler might be a solution..

Comment: Unless the stored routine is a trigger, it will not automatically run without an explicit call. The exported sql must have calls to your stored routines.

Comment: I export using cmd too --> mysqldump -u root -p database > "C:\Users\Tom\data.sql"